# What are the advantages of a soft shutter release button?

Tags: shutter, shutter-release, accessories

One of the more "exotic" accessory third-party suppliers offer for e.g. Fuji cameras are soft shutter release buttons. What is the advantage of having one of these? It sounds to me like the "softness" would impair your ability to half-press the shutter button — or am I misunderstanding what these things do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The material most *soft shutter release* buttons are made of is not the reason they are called such. Many, including [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CDJSIMS) and [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E20TNE8), are made from metal or other rigid materials.

The reason they are so called is because some users feel the larger size and raised position of the button compared to the typical small shutter release button on classically styled cameras allows for a release of the shutter that has a softer impact on the stability of the camera. YMMV.

Comment: ...and sometimes soft shutter release accessories simply have a *longer button travel* than the stock button, which some people prefer.